# Is this a proprietary function disguised as a SQL statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

In some legacy Delphi code that I need to port to C#, I have come across what seems to me to be quite a bizarr[e,o] "SQL Statement."

The TQuery component in question has a SQL property of:

```
Begin
  MAILUTIL.SEND_MAILTXT@LEOPARD('rr@crk.com', :SUB , :TEXT, 'rr@crk.com');
  MAILUTIL.SEND_MAILTXT@LEOPARD('ba@rdlands.gov', :SUB , :TEXT, 'ba@rdlands.gov');
End;
```

Normally, the SQL property is such a string as:

```
Select * from Bakery where Item = 'Pie'
```

..so this has thrown me for the proverbial loop. Is this an "Oracle thing" or what?

Comment: this is procedural style sql that is calling a database function.

Comment: Yes. It's an Oracle thing, specifically a call to functionality in `MAILUTIL`, which is most likely a collection of user-defined functions related to sending emails (UDFs because of hard-coded server name `@LEOPARD`). You'll find it in the DB somewhere (don't recall where, though). It's not standard SQL, but the Oracle drivers know what it means enough to get it through to the database.

Comment: I thought it was a function, but did not find "MAILUTIL" in Toad's listing of functions on the eponymous tab.

Comment: BTW, those email addresses that were edited were already "bogusized"

Comment: Look under "Packages" in Toad, rather than "Functions".

Comment: I looked under Packages and every other thing, including Synonyms - nothing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, oracle is able to send emails in pl/sql, but i think that is a bad practice. try to move it to whatever programming language is used outside the rdbms using that "query" or call an external script file in that situation.

reason: if the mail process fails for any reason it may rollback a whole transaction and there are other downsides, too.

Comment: -1 Sending a mail does not involve a commit, at least not when I do it so there's no rollback.

Comment: databases are not made to send emails, they are there for storing data and maybe having some business logic applied to it.

Comment: This is a really poor example to have this discussion over but that's a fairly specious argument. C#, PHP and a lot of other languages aren't designed to send e-mails either. I downvoted for the false information. Though I disagree with your comments on e-mailing that argument will go on forever...

Comment: well many things are used for something that originally was not intended and i think you agree this is also the case in this situation. also the question-user needs to port it since no other rdbms has this propritary sql extension available.

Comment: We're still going to use Oracle, although switching from Delphi to .Net/C#; Still, I'll probably move the emailing code to C#.

Comment: Oracle clearly disagrees with you about email and databases, as they offer a built-in package to do just this, and have done since 8i.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_mail.htm#i1001258

Answer (score 4):

That is a PL/SQL block (Oracle's procedural extensions to SQL).  My guess is that there is a package `MAILUTIL` defined in the remote database `LEOPARD` that has a `SEND_MAILTXT` procedure defined in the package.  `MAILUTIL` could also be a schema name and `SEND_MAILTXT` a stand-alone procedure but that seems less likely.